Apache/2.4.59 - PHP 8.3.6 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
I'm encountering an issue loading cURL into my PHP environment on Windows. Here's what I've attempted:
I installed Apache on my server (Windows server 2016) and PHP 8.3.6. However, when I run php -m in the command prompt, cURL appear in the list of loaded modules.
C:\Apache24\bin>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
gd
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

I've added PHP to my system's environment variables.
Below is an excerpt from my php.ini file:
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; https://php.net/extension-dir
;extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\php-8.3\ext"
extension=curl
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
;curl.cainfo =
curl.cainfo="C:\Program Files\php-8.3\cacert.pem"

I've also tried variations like extension=php_curl.dll and extension="C:\Program Files\php-8.3\ext\php_curl.dll" for the extension=curl line.
When I run httpd.exe -t in the Apache bin directory, it returns Syntax OK.
Any insights into why cURL isn't loading properly would be greatly appreciated.
Error:
[Tue Apr 16 10:17:26.894355 2024] [php:error] [pid 15992:tid 1188] [client ::1:62879] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in ...

Version
Apache :
Server version: Apache/2.4.59 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VS17 Server built:   Apr  4 2024 15:03:17

PHP :
PHP 8.3.6 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2024 14:54:14) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Note: I restarted Apache server on every change
Using echo "<pre>", print_r(get_loaded_extensions()), "</pre>";:
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => ctype
    [4] => date
    [5] => filter
    [6] => hash
    [7] => iconv
    [8] => json
    [9] => SPL
    [10] => pcre
    [11] => random
    [12] => readline
    [13] => Reflection
    [14] => session
    [15] => standard
    [16] => mysqlnd
    [17] => tokenizer
    [18] => zlib
    [19] => libxml
    [20] => dom
    [21] => PDO
    [22] => bz2
    [23] => SimpleXML
    [24] => xml
    [25] => xmlreader
    [26] => xmlwriter
    [27] => apache2handler
    [28] => openssl
    [29] => gd
    [30] => mbstring
    [31] => mysqli
    [32] => Phar
    [33] => pdo_mysql
    [34] => zip
)





Command-line PHP and Apache PHP are two different environments, with two different configs provided by separate php.ini files. Make sure you're checking the right one. Make a simple page test.php in your site root and put nothing but <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it. Then load that in your browser via Apache (e.g. http://localhost/test.php). That will tell you if cURL is enabled in the Apache PHP config or not. It'll also tell you where the php.ini file is for the web-based config.

Hi ADyson, I checked in phpinfo(); and I'm pointing the same php.ini

Does phpinfo() show curl enabled?

Yes it is. I updated  my question with phpinfo

Did you also check phpinfo() in the browser? That's something you haven't shared so far. Whatever php -m on the shell prints is irrelevant

Seeing Curl mentioned in the "Module Authors" section doesn't mean it's enabled. Authors are credited regardless of their modules being loaded or not. When it's enabled you get a full table titled "curl".

Looks like this.

Assuming the correct file is being edited and Apache is being restarted afterwards, perhaps you have display_startup_errors disabled.
